# How can I call Variable outside function | Reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I wanna change style when mouse move over an element but It gives me "undefined" so How can I get variable outside function scope

```
      let screenWidth = window.innerWidth;
  let screenHeight = window.innerHeight;
  let maxDegrees = 45;
  const handleMove = (event) => {
    let mouseX = event.pageX/screenWidth;
    let mouseY = event.pageY/screenHeight;
    let yDegrees = (mouseX*maxDegrees)-0.5*maxDegrees;
    let xDegrees = -0.5*((mouseY*maxDegrees)-0.5*maxDegrees);
    console.log({transform: 'rotateY('+ yDegrees + 'deg) rotateX(' + xDegrees +'deg)' });
  };
```

and there is the code of style

```
<div className='section two' id="About" onMouseMove={handleMove}>
    <div class="mainCircle" style={{transform: 'rotateY('+ yDegrees + 'deg) rotateX(' + xDegrees +'deg)' }}>
```

Comment: Why not using a css `:hover`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set a state inside the function, and use this state inside the JSX.

like so:

```
const [degree, setDegree] = useState();

  const handleMove = (event) => {
    let mouseX = event.pageX/screenWidth;
    let mouseY = event.pageY/screenHeight;
    let yDegrees = (mouseX*maxDegrees)-0.5*maxDegrees;
    let xDegrees = -0.5*((mouseY*maxDegrees)-0.5*maxDegrees);
    setDegree({ xDegrees, yDegrees });
  };

  ...
  <div class="mainCircle" style={{transform: 'rotateY('+ degree?.yDegrees || 0 + 'deg) rotateX(' + degree?.xDegrees || 0 +'deg)' }}>
  ...
```

Answer (score 0):

instead of creating a function, make an object:

```js
let obj={
    mouseX: event.pageX/screenWidth;
    mouseY: event.pageY/screenHeight;
    yDegrees: (mouseX*maxDegrees)-0.5*maxDegrees;
    xDegrees: -0.5*((mouseY*maxDegrees)-0.5*maxDegrees);
}
```

and in the jsx you can do something like:

```js
<div className='section two' id="About" onMouseMove={handleMove}>
    <div class="mainCircle" style={{transform: 'rotateY('+ obj.yDegrees + 'deg) rotateX(' + obj.xDegrees +'deg)' }}>
```

however, if some value is going to change inside the object while the component is mounted, and you want to update some values on screen (which means on re-render) then i suggest using react "state", so just store `obj` as a state, with a setter:

```js
import {useState} from 'react';

const [obj,setObj] = useState({
    mouseX: event.pageX/screenWidth;
    mouseY: event.pageY/screenHeight;
    yDegrees: (mouseX*maxDegrees)-0.5*maxDegrees;
    xDegrees: -0.5*((mouseY*maxDegrees)-0.5*maxDegrees);
    
}
```